# Set a cookie for hiding a modal window and selecting the language

Tags: cookies, modal-dialog

I have created a modal window that shows up upon loading any page in my site. I am using this modal window for language selection. I would like the users to be able to hide (1 month) the language selection modal window by clicking a hide this window button.

I have the modal window opening and loading the content in an external file as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


//name, value, additional -- expire cookie in 30 days
    jQuery.colorbox({href:'/language.php', iframe:true, open:true, width:860, height:450})
});
```

And this is the external file with the language selection menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="" />
    <style>
        #lang-container {width: 100%}
        .halfregion {display: block; float: left; width: 50%;}
        .langblock {float: left; width: 40%; background: #ebebf1; margin: .5em; padding: 0.5em; height: 230px; text-align: center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lang-container">
    <div class="halfregion">
        <h2>Choose your region</h2>
        <div class="langblock">
        <p style="text-align: center"><img src="/sites/all/themes/podsystem/images/en-us.png" width=80 alt="US region" /></p>
        <p>This site includes content and products for US, please select this region if you are in United States.</p>
        <p><a href="/en-us">US English</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="langblock">
        <p style="text-align: center"><img src="/sites/all/themes/podsystem/images/en.png" width=80 alt="International English region" /></p>
        <p>Select this region if you are outside US.</p>
        <p><a href="/">English</a></p>
        </div>
        <p><a class="hidthis" href="#">Click here to stop showing this message</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="halfregion">
        <h2>Elige tu regi&oacute;n</h2>
        <div class="langblock">
        <p style="text-align: center"><img src="/sites/all/themes/podsystem/images/es.png" width=80 alt="US region" /></p>
        <p>Selecciona esta region si hablas espa&ntilde;ol.</p>
        <p><a href="/es">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="langblock">
        <p>We are working to improve your experience using our sites. Would you like to see other languages? Drop us a comment.</p>
        <p><a href="/contact-us/contact-form">Contact us</a></p>
        </div>
        <p><a class="hidthis" href="#">Pincha aquí para dejar de mostrar este mensaje.</a></p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am really stuck now, how do I do to get the modal window to close when the users click on the links with the .hidthis class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have this issue solved, thanks.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 var setCookieTime = function (){
  var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    
  console.log(expires);
  document.cookie="regionSel=true;" + expires;
  parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();
  
 }
 
 
</script>

Comment: I also use this in the template:

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var name = "regionSel=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 var regionSel;
 for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
  if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
      regionSel = c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  }
  
  if (regionSel != "true") {
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery.colorbox({href:'/language.php', iframe:true, open:true, width:860, height:450})
  }); 
 }
 
 
 
</script>

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ suggests that you could attach `$.colorbox.close()` to the links to "initiate the close sequence."

If you don't have any more use for the plugin's functionality `$.colorbox.remove()` is also available to disable the functionality, with the provision that you no longer need it during the life of the page.